# Использование ассоциативного массива в JS и HTML

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

Пытаюсь вывести элементы массива на страницу, но вместо текста получаю `undefined`.

```js
var answers = [{
  "answer_name": "Ария Старк",
  "strong": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}, {
  "answer_name": "Джейме Ланнистер",
  "strong": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
}];

for (var ans in answers) {
  var objTo = document.getElementById("strongs");

  var newAnswer = document.createElement('div');
  newAnswer.className = "answer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3";
  newAnswer.innerHTML = "<div href='#' class='thumbnail'> <h5 class='answer-name'>" + ans.answer_name + "</h5><p class='answer-text'>" + ans.answer_name + "</div>";
  objTo.appendChild(newAnswer);
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row answers" id="strongs">
</div>
```

Comment: Уточнение для автора: структура, которую вы используете - это не ассоциативный массив, а обычный.

Comment: строго говоря _ассоциативных_ массивов в яваскрипте нет

Comment: @Daryushka если вы хотели делать `foreach`, как это делается в `php` или `c#`, к примеру, я написал ниже как это делается в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует использовать выражение

```
answers[ans]
```

Например,

```
answers[ans].answer_name
```

Так как переменная `ans` содержит индекс определенного элемента массива.

Comment: А это разве не дубль моего ответа?

Comment: @tutankhamun Нет ничего удивительного, что часто ответы на один и тот же вопрос похожи друг на друга.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что for..in - перебирает свойства объекта, для каждого свойства выполнит заданный код.
Пример.

```
var a = {
  p1: 1,
  p2: 2
}
for(var p in a) {
  alert(p) // p1, затем p2

  // к значению каждого свойства прибавить 1
  a[p] = a[p] + 1
}
```

В вашем случае `ans` будет равен 0, 1 и т.д. Соответственно `ans.answer_name` на самом деле выглядит `0.answer_name`, `1.answer_name` и т.д.

Вам нужно примеминить либо обычный `for`:

`for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; ++i)`

Либо писать так:

`answers[ans].answer_name`

Либо применять `foreach` (что, думаю, вы и пытались делать ):

```
answers.forEach(function(item) {    
  var objTo = document.getElementById("strongs");

  var newAnswer = document.createElement('div');
  newAnswer.className = "answer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3";
  newAnswer.innerHTML = "<div href='#' class='thumbnail'> <h5 class='answer-name'>" + item.answer_name + "</h5><p class='answer-text'>" + item.answer_name + "</div>";
  objTo.appendChild(newAnswer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Цикл `for` в вашем случае перебирает ключи массива (то есть индексы элементов). Обращаться к полям элементов нужно, например, так: `answers[ans].answer_name`